# SAS using macro in a title

Tags: sas, sas-macro

What is the purpose of title Title "&TitleX" here?

Is there any difference between doing the first and second way?

```
%let TitleX=PROC PRINT Of Only &Cyl_Count Cylinder Vehicles; %let Cyl_Count=5;
Title "&TitleX";
proc print data=sashelp.cars;
where Cylinders=&Cyl_Count;
var Type Make Model Cylinders MSRP; run;


title PROC PRINT Of Only &Cyl_Count Cylinder Vehicles; %let Cyl_Count=5;
proc print data=sashelp.cars;
where Cylinders=&Cyl_Count;
var Type Make Model Cylinders MSRP; run;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two differences. One is that the macro variable exists and can be used for something else if you want. The second is how the TITLE statement is generated. The version that is using the TITLEX macro variables is using quotes and the other is not, but that really doesn't have anything to do with the macro variable.